# Coldfusion 10 Add More Memory

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We currently have a CF 10 Instance which we are monitoring via seeFusion.

We currently have 12GB of memory on this particular machine and whilst monitoring it within the server monitor it never skips a beat and appears to be quite reliable.

However whilst in seeFusion, the CF Instance appears to only have 486MB of memory...

I would like to bump this up as since it only has 486MB of memory, simple things like running a cfindex on a dataset of 40,000 records makes the entire server crash.

Any ideas on how to go about adding more memory to the CF Instance? Either by the Admin or programatically if this is possible ?

Comment: This question will be better suited for ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the size of the JVM Heap in the Coldfusion Administrator in the Java and JVM section. This thread has some useful information and links: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1027056